# Getting the sum of 2 tables columns by group by or joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Good Day!!

i need help i have a 2 table named

### ex_bulacan

1.qty
2.remarks
3.delivered_date

### ex_depot

1.qty
2.remarks
3.delivered_date

what i want to do is get the sum of both qty
with the remarks only 'DELIVERED' and it will
group by delivered date with the date format of 'MM YYYY'

how can i query that? please help i am new in SQL
i'm using ORACLE 11g XE for database and
APEX for application
i will use this query to create a chart..
please help MASTER's

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(qty), remarks, delivered_date FROM
    (SELECT qty, remarks, delivered_date FROM ex_bulacan
     UNION ALL
     SELECT qty, remarks, delivered_date FROM ex_depot)
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(delivered_date, 'MM YYYY')
HAVING remarks='DELIVERED'
```

I'm not entirely sure about the TO_CHAR function, but this should do the trick. I'm a nested query as the "table" for the outer query. The inner query actually merges the output of two queries with the UNION keyword, and then makes this resulting dataset "available" to the outer query.

Comment: Let me know how it works. Just threw it up; wasn't able to test. If it doesn't let me know what you get back.

Comment: i edit your code like this " SELECT SUM(qty_bags), remarks, TO_CHAR(date_time_recieved, 'MM YYYY') as delivered_date FROM
    (SELECT qty_bags, remarks, date_time_recieved FROM ex_bulacan WHERE remarks = 'DELIVERED'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT qty_bags, remarks, received_date FROM ex_depot WHERE remarks = 'DELIVERED')
GROUP BY date_time_recieved;" and i got this error "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 29 Column: 22" thanks please help!! @PaulB.

Comment: Okay, @MichaelPilapil, try the above change to my code, adapting as needed.

Comment: i'm still getting that error sir here i edited your code "SELECT SUM(qty), remarks, TO_CHAR(delivered_date, 'MM YYYY') as delivered_date FROM
    (SELECT qty, remarks, delivered_date FROM ex_bulacan
     UNION ALL
     SELECT qty, remarks, delivered_date FROM ex_depot)
GROUP BY delivered_date
HAVING remarks='DELIVERED'"

Comment: Also, as you adapt the inner queries to get them to do what you need, you must remember to make the names and order of the columns you select in your `UNION`ed queries to match. Otherwise, you'll generate a SQL error.

Comment: Okay, try the latest change I made.

Comment: may i ask @PaulB where did you get the "DELIVERED_DATE" column in the 1st select in what table did you get that?

Comment: From you. In the original post. You list the fields under the table names.

Comment: from the 1st table? the ex_bulcan?

Answer (score 0):

First create a view with this sql statement;

```
SELECT qty, remarks, delivered_date FROM ex_bulacan
UNION
SELECT qty, remarks, delivered_date FROM ex_depot
```

Then you can query from that view with a sql statement something like following (i didn't test it)

```
SELECT SUM(qty) AS qty_total FROM your_view_name GROUP BY TO_CHAR(delivered_date, 'MM YYYY') HAVING remarks='DELIVERED'
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: instead of creating view, you can directly query from sql result by putting my first sql statement in place of your_view_name in second sql statement.

Comment: btw, if you want same rows from both tables should be in combined result, you should use UNION ALL instead of UNION

Comment: Sir.. i try your code but still get the error "SELECT SUM(qty) AS qty_total FROM your_view_name GROUP BY TO_CHAR(delivered_date, 'MM YYYY') HAVING remarks='DELIVERED'" the error is "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 62 Column: 102" please help

Comment: please try this: `SELECT SUM(qty) AS qty_total, TO_CHAR(delivered_date, 'MM YYYY') FROM your_view_name GROUP BY TO_CHAR(delivered_date, 'MM YYYY') HAVING remarks='DELIVERED'` i can't test it due to i have no oracle database i can access right now :(

Comment: or try this `SELECT SUM(qty) AS qty_total, TO_CHAR(delivered_date, 'MM YYYY')

FROM
(
SELECT qty, remarks, delivered_date FROM ex_bulacan WHERE remarks='DELIVERED'
UNION
SELECT qty, remarks, delivered_date FROM ex_depot WHERE remarks='DELIVERED'
)

GROUP BY TO_CHAR(delivered_date, 'MM YYYY')`

Comment: sir just got the correct answer from your answer!! Thanks for that!!